# Has anyone come up with a Match Case icon?

Tags: icons, interface, labels, internationalisation

I have noticed that many major applications, such as Firefox, use the literal text `Match Case` (in English) on UI buttons in order to allow the user to specify that the *Find* function should match the case of the user-supplies text.

Are there any icons that relay the same meaning as `Match Case` to the user?

***Update:***

I am not interested in a specific icon for personal or corporate use in any application.  I am interested in knowing if there are one or more standard graphical icons that convey this idea, as most applications choose to write it out at `Match Case` or `Case Sensitive` in their UI's.

Answer (score 1):

`Aa` is used in Visual Studio :)